# How to make my android app clean?

Tags: android, debugging

In my Java code, I use the `Debug` flag to control debug model, if is debug ,there are some extra functions,such as:sway the phone show a `activity` to change app version. Now I want to erase these code when publishing the code to market.

Like the code below, is there a way to make `VersionSwitchService.class` code is `null` and other code is running normal?

I mean that even if, someone decompiles the apk, `VersionSwitchService.class` code is seen as blank.

```
if (isDEBUG) {
    VersionSwitchService.libStart(this, new LibVersionSwitch() {

        @Override
        public void versionSwitchToOnline() {
            //...
        }

        @Override
        public void versionSwitch(String version) {
            //...
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make `isDebug` `final static`:

```
final static boolean isDebug = false;
```

the Java compiler will complete remove the parts of code that are unreached. Sp in your example, the 'then'-part is completely omitted and thus not available in your apk.

Furthermore, when creating a (release) apk build, the Android tools will strip all methods and classes that are unused. So, if your `VersionSwitchService` class is only used for debugging, it will not present (due to the combination of the `static final` debug constant)

Comment: thanks,but isDebug is dynamic assignment,I won't to change it when pack release version.

Comment: That is fine by me, but as far as I know this is the only method in Java to let the compiler remove chunks of code that are (100% certain) not used...

Comment: I tried your method,and  decompile the apk file,but the VersionSwitchService class is still there.

Comment: [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) removes the unused classes/methods. Did you enable it? (By default it is disabled)